# how prevent rotation with teb_local_planner

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using navigation stack and using teb_local_planner for path planning.
I change this parameter  "max_vel_x_backwards: 0.0" so the robot will not move backwards.
But I also want the robot not to rotate on itself.
how can I do?

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L16ELP4HGjK2i8kClT3wgSSdzx-w444n/view?usp=sharing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275405/how-prevent-rotation-with-teb_local_planner/) by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnMdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/11471/johnmdz/) on 2018-06-28**:
Hello,

I am facing the same problem. I have a robot that rotates with a 1.4m radius and that is not able to perform backwards movements (or lets say that I truly prefer it doesn't due to security reasons). Did you manage to find a solution?

Thank you

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-28**:
have you tried adjusting the turning radius parameter?

**Comment by [JohnMdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/11471/johnmdz/) on 2018-07-02**:
I have. And that part seems to be working. The problem is the backward movement. My robot cannot perform backward movement. I'd be comfortable with a message from the planner saying it is impossible to find a path...

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-02**:
@JohnMdz i tried what you said, it looks like I am also facing the same issue. I am also getting the same warning about control loop missing its desired refresh rate. I would like to know if @pietrocolombo has figured this out or not ...

**Comment by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on 2018-07-06**:
@JohnMdz we have not solved the issue.
on the other hand we are developing another local planner

**Comment by [jorgyz](https://answers.ros.org/users/40727/jorgyz/) on 2019-04-04**:
@JohnMdz did you ever find a way to handle the backwards movement issue?

**Comment by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on 2019-04-05**:
unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I can understand you want your robot to avoid in-place rotations and moving backwards.
Avoiding both backing up and in-place rotations can get your robot stuck if there is an obstacle in front of it. In this case the recovery-behavior will take place to get the robot unstuck (NOTE that the default recovery behavior rotates in place). That is set by the recovery_behaviors and clearing_rotation_allowed parameters from [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base). This means that in order to avoid in-place rotations when stuck you will need a custom recovery behavior plugin in this case. 
Please post your teb_local_planner parameters (.yaml) and move_base.launch files so we can see your current configuration.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnMdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/11471/johnmdz/) on 2018-07-11**:
I don't fully agree. I understand that the robot may be stuck if it unable to perform backwards or in place movements/rotations. My main issue is that the planner always consider the backwards movement and not only in obstacle avoidance situations.